# Comments/Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to Visual studio. My question is if you comment out your code then write a new piece of code in which you make a mistake. In this case, does this occur that the commented code is still working?
Until I have not spotted a mistake in my new code, the old code was executed. Is it normal?

Comment: commented code is never executed.  If you are having issues with some code you need to post it, along with the expected and actual results otherwise no one can help.

Comment: This is Visual Studio "101" - this link may help you get started. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492171.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your new code does not compile and you try and run your application Visual Studio will give you the option to run the previous version. It sounds like maybe this is what you are seeing?

I.e. If you see this dialog:

[image: build errors dialog]

Then your new code did not compile and if you click Yes your old code will run.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i see. Now I understand why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Commented code is not executed. Make sure you clean and rebuild your project. If you have older versions of your project built, sometimes VS will forget to rebuild, and you'll run the older version instead.

Build > Clean Solution

Build > Build Solution

Comment: I think it executes the last sucessful build and comments do not make any difference.  Thank you.